# Как из группы в ВК сделать мобильное приложение?

Tags: android, вконтакте, архитектура, мобильные-приложения

Вопрос по архитектуре.Необходимо из группы в вк создать красивое приложение. Надо ли запускать свой сервер, куда будет парситься то что нужно с постов группы, а потом приложение будет красиво выводить что напарсили и кинули на свой сервер. Или можно сразу с группы в приложение выводить в нужном виде. Есть опыт написания оффлайн-приложения, но сейчас необходимо научиться работать  с вебом. С чего начать, от чего оттолкнуться?

Comment: начать с изучения vk api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в гугле набири vk api android, он тебя дасть ссылку на [sdk vk](https://vk.com/dev/android_sdk) и на [github](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk) есть пример